# Dynamics AX 2009 Report: LabelPosition above does not work?

Tags: reporting, dynamics-ax-2009

I'm just in the process of changing the SalesInvoice Report. One thing I'm trying to do is show the label of some items not left of the item value but above it instead.

Seems easy enough: just change the LabelPosition (for example from CustInvoiceJour_InvoiceId) setting from "left" to "above" and voila: the label has vanished. It is just shown nowhere at all.
Strange. I would have expected the label to show up, well, above the content. Not to vanish.

Am I missing something (there is no label height to set), or is this functionality broken?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this functionality is broken. But in generated design, these elements will not show the label if it's set to above:

- Prolog
- PageHeader
- Header
- Footer
- Epilog
- ProgrammableSection

If the item you're trying to change is in one of those, then the label position above will, from my experience, not work.

My tip is to create a new control of the text type and then use the same label that the extended data type for the field uses under the "text" property and then adjust the position so it is positioned above the field you're trying to set a label on.

Comment: My example above (CustInvoiceJour_InvoiceId) is of type Field String, so I'd expect the label to show up above the content when I change the label position.

Comment: It won't. As I explained, it just doesn't show up unless you manually create a text field and enter the label you want in it and placing it above your item. Now there might be a other way. But by simply putting "labelPosition: above" in one of those elements will result in the label not showing.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have noticed for a ProgrammableSection  the column name labels are not shown only on the first page of the report. The labels are shown on the next pages.